# Книга по SQL и её создание таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql

читаю книгу по SQL и там вот такое создание таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  order_num  int      NOT NULL ,
  order_date date     NOT NULL ,
  cust_id    char(10) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
  cust_id      char(10)  NOT NULL ,
  cust_name    char(50)  NOT NULL ,
  cust_address char(50)  ,
  cust_city    char(50)  ,
  cust_state   char(5)   ,
  cust_zip     char(10)  ,
  cust_country char(50)  ,
  cust_contact char(50)  ,
  cust_email   char(255) 
);
```

Книжка если честно очень многому научила в своё время за короткий срок, но вот теперь не пойму в том же `cust_zip` есть такое значение: `D352GD` и такое: `235412`. Мы сделали это поле char или varchar только потому что тип int не сможет хранить в себе вот такое значение: `D352GD`? А можно ли хранить целые числа в char или varchar, ну то есть будут ли проблемы ли хранить целые числа в строке? Почему вообще там где тот же `cust_id` стоит тип `char`?

Comment: Это "SQL для домохозяек", адназначна... даже не для чайников.

Comment: @Akina не очень понял вас)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> будут ли проблемы ли хранить целые числа в строке?

**Во-первых**, последовательность цифр - это не всегда число. Например, `000001` и `001` - это разные строки. А числа были бы одинаковыми.

Почтовый индекс (zip), ИНН, и всякие разные коды общероссийских классификаторов - это не числа.

Числа предполагают выполнения над ними арифметических операций, а строки - только конкатенацию и извлечение подстроки.

**Во-вторых**, хранить числа как строки в SQL можно. Это редко оправданно, но можно.

> Почему вообще там где тот же `cust_id` стоит тип `char`?

А это вопрос к автору книги/примера.